# How do I properly select a row in ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I'm using ObjectListView with C# and .Net 4.0. I wrote code that reloads the listview and then re-selects the last selected index.

The re-selection code is quite simple:

```
olvListView.SelectedIndex = i;
```

This appears to work, because the item is selected. However, if I then click the up or down arrow, the selection jumps up to the second row (no matter what row I selected), suggesting that the selection was actually set on the first row, no matter what was the value of i.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying ListView Control distinguishes between 'selection' and 'focus'.

`olvListView.SelectedIndex = i;` changes the selection but not the focus. But the focused row is the one that the keyboard input relates to.

Either change the focus the as well

```
olvListView.SelectedIndex = i;
olvListView.FocusedItem = olvListView.SelectedItems[0];
```

or call

```
olvListView.SelectObject(aModelObject);
```

The second solution would be the preferred way to select an item when working with OLV, however you say you "wrote code that reloads the listview", so the reference to the original item is probably different. Maybe you should just refresh the items that changed, instead of reloading everything. That way you could preserve the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Example if your olv have datasource from "class_z.list" and foreach have only one result.

```
    foreach(class_z a in class_z.list.Where(x=>x.id==id_value))
            {
                olv.SelectedObject = z;
            }
```